# Painting a rounded border onto a JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, border

I am trying to paint a rounded rectangle around a `JScrollPane`. For the life of me I can't figure out how to do this! No matter what I try, the border is not visible. I have figured out that it is drawing *BEHIND* the contents and not over them. The only thing inside the scroll pane is a `JPanel` with some graphics painted onto it.  Does anyone know how to fix this?

Here is the code I have tried to paint the border on the scroll pane:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

    g2.setColor(Color.black);
    g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1));
    g2.draw(new RoundRectangle2D.Double(0, 0, getWidth() - 1, getHeight() - 1, 10, 10));
}
```

I have also tried using `paint` instead of `paintComponent` but with no such luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually painting outside of the components bounds, which is a big no-no, and is why you are having this problem. You should consider creating a custom [Border](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/border/Border.html) or extending the component insets so that you have room to paint your outline

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!! How would I do that?

Comment: You should investigate Border and its subclasses, determine if any of them fit your requirements (PlainBorder might), and investigate how Borders use Insets to create more space around a Component

Answer (score 1):

This needs nothing custom.  Simply use a [`LineBorder(lineColor,thickness,roundedCorners)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/border/LineBorder.html#LineBorder-java.awt.Color-int-boolean-)..

> Creates a line border with the specified color, thickness, and corner shape.

Where..

> `roundedCorners` - whether or not border corners should be round